# HTML textbox in table turns to a label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox, label

I currently have a table which contains text box for users to fill in. I also have a button which turns the text box value into a label or just a string for display.

Lets say, the table code looks like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="box1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="box2"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="box3"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="box4"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="box5"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="box6"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The button code looks like this

```
<button id="convert">Press me</button>
```

After I pressed the button, I wish the text box becomes the text label, what ways do you guys suggest I can deal with this problem?
I don't mind using any type of code, php, javascript will be a better option for me.

Thanks

Comment: You mean not editable?

Comment: @Alexis I have googled some websites, but still no clue on that. I tried to wrap the <input type="text" name="box1"> with the <label>, but after that, I have no idea what to do

Comment: Instead of turning your input text into a label, you can just disable your input text :)

Comment: @ThumChoonTat Yea, what I want is after the button "Press Me" is pressed, it becomes not editable, the textbox disappears, and becomes the label

Comment: @Pranav provided a good answer

Comment: @Souregi I thought of that as well, but the reason behind is because I am gonna use javascript and scarp the data from the table and export it as csv, I have tried a couple of examples showing how to do so, but when the table contains text box, it does not work, so I reckon it should be changed to a label or just some text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach click event handler to the button and within the callback iterate and generate the label based on the value.

```js
// attach click event handler
document.getElementById('convert').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // get all input element and convert 
  // into array using Array.from or
  // use [].slice.call for older browser
  // and then iterate over them
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table input')).forEach(function(ele) {
    // generate label element
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    // update the html content with input value
    label.innerHTML = ele.value;
    // replace the input element with label
    ele.parentNode.replaceChild(label, ele);
  });
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="box1">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="box2">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="box3">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="box4">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="box5">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="box6">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <table>
    <button id="convert">Press me</button>
```

Comment: What if i want to exclude box1 from the conversion? Just box 2 to 6?

Comment: @5am50n : `document.querySelectorAll('table input:not([name='box1'])')` .... use `:not()` with attribute equals selector

Answer (score 1):

Here is `jquery` version.

References:[jQuery-replaceWith.](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

```
$('#convert').click(function(){
    $('input').each(function(){
      var value=$(this).val();
      $(this).replaceWith('<label>' + value+'</label>');
    });
});
```

```js
$('#convert').click(function(){
     $('input').each(function(){
    var value=$(this).val();
         $(this).replaceWith('<label>' + value+'</label>');
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="box1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="box2"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="box3"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="box4"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="box5"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="box6"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button id="convert">Press me</button>
```